# Grails JSON max length

Tags: json, tomcat, grails, groovy

I am aware that JSON strings often have a max length defined in either Apache on PHP, however where is the max length for JSON strings defined in Grails using TomCat?

The JSON string I am sending is 13,636 characters in length, however I can shorten it a lot (although I don't want to while we're testing) - also, we may be sending images via JSON in the future which I've read requires base64 encoding and thus a considerable overhead. If we were to do such a thing then I am worried that if this limit is causing problems, it's something we should overcome now.

If there is no limit, then **perhaps I am doing something wrong**. I have a finite amount of domain objects that I am encoding as JSON using `domainInstance as grails.converters.deep.JSON` - this is done using a `for` loop and each time the JSON string is appended to a `StringBuilder`

I then render the StringBuilder in a view using `render(stringBuilder.toString())` and the first JSON string is fine, however the second is truncated near to the end. If I were to guestimate I'd say I am getting around 80% of the total length of the StringBuilder.

**EDIT/SOLUTION**: Apologies guys & girls, I've noticed that when I `view source` on the page I get the complete JSON string, however when I just view the page it's truncated. It's an odd error, I'll accept answers on why it's truncated, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There *is* a maximum size in Tomcat for POST requests, which you may be concerned with later if you start sending huge JSON / Base64 image requests (like you mentioned).

The default value in tomcat is 2,097,152 bytes (2 MB); it can be changed by setting the `maxPostSize` attribute of the `<Connector>` in server.xml.

[From the docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/ajp.html) (for `maxPostSize` in Tomcat 7):

> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the
>   container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by
>   setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not
>   specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

This is pretty straightforward to configure if you're deploying a Grails war to a standalone Tomcat instance. However, I can't find much about actually configuring server.xml if you're using the tomcat [plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/tomcat). If it were me, I'd probably just run large-file tests using the war instead of with grails run-app.

Comment: Cheers Rob! I'm currently only using `grails run-app` but will test thoroughly before we start deploying. :)