# JSON Data Limit

Tags: java, javascript, json, grails

We have grails 2.2.4 application running on Tomcat that works with user camera and keystrokes, collects some data on the client side with Javascript and sends using POST.

In the view that collects data we have:

```
<g:form name="testResultsForm" id="testResultsForm" controller="customer" action="thankYou" method="post">
<h3>Dummy data!</h3>

<input type="text" style="visibility: hidden" name="testResults" id="testResults"/>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit dummy data</button>
</g:form>
```

In the JS, we assign all camera data to this html element and submit the form:

```
TestUtils.setValue('testResults', sendData);
$("#testResultsForm").submit();
```

In the grails controller we have the following line to parse the JSON:

`def data = JSON.parse(params.testResults)`

Everything works as expected except for when the user takes longer than normal and puts in  lots of keystrokes. The errors looks something like:

```
2014-06-14 01:22:14,323 [http-8443-16] ERROR (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver) - JSONException occurred when processing request: [POST] /qbcheck/customer/thankYou
Expected a ',' or ']' at character 524288 of {"patkey":"","test_version":"1.4","data_version":"1.3","patientid":"","test_date":"","test_duration":0,"gender":"","dob":"","fov":62,"fps":26,"scale_factor":0,"country":46,"camera_data":{"x":[353,353,353,353,3......
```

It always fails at character 524288. This led us to investigate that there might be a limit on the amount of data, we looked at Tomcat and found that it allows 2MB data by default using maxpostsize property. Still we updated it to a bigger number just to be sure. Similarly, we tried looking on Grails and JS side but were not able to find any limitation.

Looking for any pointers in this regard. We are able to provide more details as required.

Comment: this will help you :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430214/grails-json-max-length

Comment: @johnSmith we already tried that as I mentioned in the question without any success, so it seems like the limitation is somewhere else

Comment: is your tomcat the first server in the chain?  or is there some other httpd, proxy or firewall in front of it, that might apply a limit?

Comment: @cfrick, he uses apache + tomcat, tomcat limitations was fixed with `maxPostSize="0"`, but now there is some kind of `proxy error` during json parsing (maybe parsing takes too much time)

Comment: a user is typing 524288 chars - maybe the client should limit the saize adn valdiate beforehand anyway

Comment: @NimChimpsky - a user is not typing these characters. This is a 10 minute test that records head movements through the camera and also user's keystrokes on the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that the html "input" has a hard limit of 512 KB. Ideally, we should have received some kind of error/warning when trying to assign more data to an input value through JS. However, that does not happen

So we changed the input which was previously defined as:

```
<input type="text" style="visibility: hidden" name="testResults" id="testResults"/>
```

To a text-area:

```
<textarea style="visibility: hidden" name="testResults" id="testResults"/>
```

And this allowed us to transfer data greater than 512 KB.